# how does one manually log out when using devise http authentication?

Tags: ruby, devise, rack

I'm very new to Ruby, and have inherited an API that (I believe) uses devise to handle http authentication.

I was trying to test a route, and accidentally logged in with incorrect credentials. However, now I am "stuck", as I cannot find a way to manually log myself out (nor did this API have a way to do it via a route), so i can log in with the correct credentials.

I am wondering if there is a way via the command line (or some other manual means) to simply log out.

I'm pretty noob at the moment, so I hope this question even makes sense. It's worth noting that this does not use rails, but uses rack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easiest and quickest, just kill the browser (which will destroy your session)